# Run EXE and later send text

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to run Powershell in background to start EXE and wait to get message "input servies Name" then write "xxx"

note:
I don`t want use SendKeys or feature that required UI
also EXE not support parameter to pass it

Sample:

The test.exe VB.NET console application. How can I send Yes to appplication to start the servies.

Module test

```
Sub Main()

    Console.WriteLine("Input 'Yes' to Start Server")

    Dim MyX = Console.ReadLine

    If MyX = "Yes" Then

        Console.WriteLine("Service Started ...")

    Else

        Console.WriteLine("Job ESC ...")

    End If

End Sub
```

End test

---

Power Shell

$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName "localhost"

Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {
C:\test\test.exe
Yes

} 
Remove-PSSession $s

---

Rueslt:

PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Users\e000136\Desktop\Untitled1.ps1

Input 'Yes' to Start Server

Job ESC ...

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service nor a forum. Own research and code attempts are expected.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we are here to help you with code you are having issues with, but, well, you ar not showing any.

*So, follow what LotPings is suggesting.*

Yet, so as not to send you away empty handed. Just about almost anything is doable, as long as you know what you want and how to go about it. Yet, again:

Where is your code you are trying?

What have you researched?

PowerShell has jobs cmdlets. Look at the examples in the help file on how to use the.

```
Get-Command -Name '*job' | Format-Table -AutoSize

# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Start-Job).Parameters
Get-help -Name Start-Job -Full
Get-help -Name Start-Job -Online
Get-help -Name Start-Job -Examples

(Get-Command -Name Get-Job).Parameters
Get-help -Name Get-Job -Full
Get-help -Name Get-Job -Online
Get-help -Name Get-Job -Examples

(Get-Command -Name Receive-Job).Parameters
Get-help -Name Receive-Job -Full
Get-help -Name Receive-Job -Online
Get-help -Name Receive-Job -Examples
```

Put something together and come back if it is not working. Well, that is if you have not already.

See also, if you have not used jobs before.

[Understanding Background Jobs in PowerShell](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/04/18/background-jobs-in-powershell.aspx)

***Update for the OP***

Thanks for the code, but if your exe code has this as a argument, then just pass it in…

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName "localhost"
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { C:\test\test.exe } -ArgumentList 'Yes'
Remove-PSSession $s
```

See also:
[PowerShell – Passing Parameters as Variables using Remote Management and Invoke-Command](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ralphkyttle/2015/06/04/powershell-passing-parameters-as-variables-using-remote-management-and-invoke-command/)

[Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6)

> ***-ArgumentList***
>
> Supplies the values of local variables in the command. The variables in the command are replaced by these values before the
>   command is run on the remote computer. Enter the values in a
>   comma-separated list. Values are associated with variables in the
>   order that they are listed. The alias for ArgumentList is Args.
>
> The
>   values in the ArgumentList parameter can be actual values, such as
>   1024, or they can be references to local variables, such as $max.
>
> To use local variables in a command, use the following command format:
>
> {param($\[, $\]...)
>   \} -ArgumentList \ -or-
>   \
>
> The param keyword lists the local variables that
>   are used in the command. ArgumentList supplies the values of the
>   variables, in the order that they are listed.